# What is the best way to stream videos to iOS from Google Cloud Bucket?

Tags: python, swift, google-app-engine, video, google-cloud-storage

I am currently developing an app that allows people to watch videos. However, these videos are stored in Google Cloud bucket. My back-end is in Python. I can currently grab the credentials in Python then download the video, but cant get the video from Python to the iOS app. Or i could stream the video straight to the phone from the server with a HTTP request, however I need the access token which for the life of me I can not find. What is the best approach for streaming these videos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Streaming video through your backend is not very efficient - it's slower and you pay for extra instance hours. A better option is to stream directly from the Cloud Storage bucket.

If your videos are not publicly accessible, the best option is to [create a signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#signed-urls) using your backend, and then pass it to the client. The client can use this signed URL to access content directly from the Cloud Storage.

You may find [this example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-signedurls-python/blob/master/gcs-signed-url-example.py) useful.

Comment: A quick question about these signed urls. say i have mutliple users watching multiple videos. Can i create a lot of signed urls ?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no limit as long as all signed URLs come from the same project. The documentation mentions somewhere that only if you use different projectIDs, you need to create a copy of the file.

Comment: The link that you posted with the github signed url python file. can you help me? How do I use this? or where do I get started? how o I put this into my API?